# SQL Server 2008 service pack installation error

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

When I am trying to install the SQL Server 2008 service pack I am getting the error as:

> There are no SQL Server instances or shared features that can be
>   updated on this computer, and The version of SQL Server instance
>   Shared Component does not match the version expected by the SQL Server
>   update. The installed SQL Server product version is 10.50.1750.9, and
>   the expected SQL Server version is 10.0.1600.22.

The product version is not matching so what should I need to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need to run the [SQL Server 2008 R2 service pack](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26727) instead, since that's the product you seem to have installed.